# Defining a Function using the Power Series

Tags: power-series

. [image: Power Series]

I understand c & d as fairly simple first and second derivatives of a multivariable function @ t = 0. But it escapes me on whether it is acceptable to separate the functions and do the product rule.

I do not understand what I'm being asked in a & b. Isn't the domain of M defined for all values of t since e^0 is simply 1?

I have no clue what explicit function is being represented by the power series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

**a)** The [Ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) should help you.

**b)** If you set $$\alpha=\frac{6e^t}{11}$$ your series is of the form
$$\frac{5}{6}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha^k$$
that you should be able to compute.

Comment: That would help me computationally, but I don't see how computing the power series helps me find the answers to a through d. Should I be computing the power series first, and then computing the derivatives or trying to figure out the explicit function?

Comment: Do you know some condition for whether a geometric series converges?

Comment: You should know that $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$ and that the series converge if and only if $|a|<1$.

Comment: I recall that a power series can converge for some values of n along a radius, and diverge for others. It's been a few years since I looked at series of any sort so it alludes me as to what I'm even being asked to do.

Comment: You have now all elements to solve questions a) and b) :-)

Comment: IS the ratio test applicable here? I can't find a common ratio

Comment: Of course, just compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\frac{6^{n+1}e^{(n+1)t}}{11^{n+1}}}{\frac{6^ne^{nt}}{11^n}}$$ and find a condition on $t$ such that the limit is smaller than $1$. (you will have some $\ln$)

Comment: I was able to simplify it all the way down to (6t/11t) * (n+1)/n). This means then that the series converges when 6t/11t < 1?

Comment: No, $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\frac{6^{n+1}e^{(n+1)t}}{11^{n+1}}}{\frac{6^ne^{nt}}{11^n}}=\frac{6}{11} e^t$$ and thus, it converge if $$\frac{6}{11}e^t<1\implies e^t<\frac{11}{6}\implies t<\ln\left(\frac{11}{6}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

For $a$, you're probably going to want to use the $root-test$ and see what happens to 
$\sqrt{\frac{5\cdot 6^{n-1} e^{nt}}{11^n}}$. as $n$ goes to infinity. From that you solve which $t$ lets the series converge

For $b$. Let's manipulate the series a little bit
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{5\cdot 6^{n-1} e^{nt}}{11^n} \\
\frac{5}{6} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\frac{6e^t}{11} \right)^n
$$
That's just a geometric power series, and you know what the summation of that is.

Comment: For b, you calculate the summation by using 1/1-r? With 6e^t being the r? How does this help us find the function?

Comment: Well, $6e^t /11$ is the $r$, but right idea.